# Удаление \r\n из текста

Tags: php

У меня задача повторить  запрос одной программы, я отследил в wireshark-е ее ответ [image: такой ответ от сервера мне нужен]

Но я получаю при моем php коде  вот это: 
[image: что выдает мой php код]

Как видите в конце EndTime есть символы \r\n, как их убрать?
Вот мой код:

```
<?php
$f = "CurrentTime=17.3.2019\r"; 
$o = "EndTime=18.03.2019"; 
$io = $f . $o; 
echo $io;
?>
```

Comment: Уберите `?>` ..

Comment: @andreymal то что надо, огромное спасибо